# Split data in Excel

Tags: sql-server-2012, excel-2010

I currently have a spreadsheet that looks like this.

```
Client_ID             State
1091                  AR,FL,HI,LA,MI,OR
```

This is the outcome I would like, every state to be spilt into a new row.

```
Client_ID             State
1091                  AR
1091                  FL
1091                  HI
1091                  LA
1091                  MI
1091                  OR
```

Comment: What function can I use in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the input is in **Sheet1** and the output will go in **Sheet2** in columns **A & B.**
Run this small macro:

```
Sub ReOrganizeData()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim c1 As String, c2 As String
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    c1 = "A"
    c2 = "B"
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, c1).End(xlUp).Row
    K = 2

    For i = 2 To N
        v1 = s1.Cells(i, c1).Value
        v2 = s1.Cells(i, c2).Value
        ary = Split(v2, ",")
        For j = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            s2.Cells(K, c1).Value = v1
            s2.Cells(K, c2).Value = ary(j)
            K = K + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```